# Como mandar mais de um valor pelo return

Tags: php, pdo

Eu estou realizando uma consulta na banco e quero retorna mais de uma valor da consulta como eu faço isso?

A estrutura da minha tabela e a seguinte

```
Id_idx | name | OUTROS |
```

Cada Id_idx pode ser repetido ate 3 vezes quero contar quantos linhas são retornadas que é a primeira parte de código e também retorna os valores das outra colunas.

Aqui só vai retorna a quantidade de linhas.

```
$char = $pdoG->prepare("SELECT * FROM u_hero WHERE id_idx = :id");
$char->bindValue(":id",$id);
$char->execute();
$chars = $char->rowCount();
return $chars;
```

Enquanto aqui vai me retorna as informações.

```
$char = $pdoG->prepare("SELECT * FROM u_hero WHERE id_idx = :id");
$char->bindValue(":id",$id);
$char->execute();
$chars = $char->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
return $chars;
```

Como faço para unir esses `return` em um único `static function`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode usar um array no `return`:

```
$char = $pdoG->prepare("SELECT * FROM u_hero WHERE id_idx = :id");
$char->bindValue(":id",$id);
$char->execute();

return array(
    'datos' => $char->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    'total' => $char->rowCount()
);
```

Quando a função retornar você pode iterar os dados, algo como:

```
Total: <?php echo $variavel['total']; ?><br>

<!-- vai iterar os resultados -->
<?php foreach ($variavel['dados'] as $linha): ?>

    <!-- vai iterar os valores por coluna -->
    <?php foreach ($linha as $coluna => $valorColuna): ?>
    <?php echo $coluna, ': ', $valorColuna; ?><br>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

<s>Se quer consultar mais de uma ID pode fazer assim:</s>

```
function minhaFuncao(array $ids) {
    $query = str_repeat('id_idx = ? OR ', count($ids));
    $query = substr($query, 0, -4);//Remove o OR extra do final

    $char = $pdoG->prepare("SELECT * FROM u_hero WHERE " . $query);

    foreach ($ids as $id) {
        $char->bindValue(1, $id);
    }

    $char->execute();

    return $char->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
```

E consultaria assim:

```
$idsParaConsulta = array(
   1, 5, 8, 4, 20
);

print_r(minhaFuncao($idsParaConsulta));
```

Comment: Dentro de cara linha tem o id do play e ele pode ter 3 hero então o id_idx é o id do play por isso vem ate 3 consultar com dados diferentes porem o id_idx igual.

Comment: editei acho que agora vai ficar melhor de alguém me ajuda, achei que daquele jeito seria suficiente desculpes.

Comment: bem 3 heros por que podem ser criados ate 3 heros = 3 linhas do banco, eu tenho um id em comum que é o id_idx quero contar e pegar os dados independentes de cada linha.

Comment: Guilherme so quero juntar o $chars = $char->rowCount(); com o $chars = $char->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);, mais já que vai vim mais de uma consulta as vezes já que pode ter ate 3 linhas quero saber como junto essas duas linhas e mando no return.

Comment: A ultima pergunta para eu aceitar sua resposta, tem como eu acessar os dados de cada linha independente? @Guilherme

Comment: eu fiz assim, foreach ($chars["dados"] as $info) {
   echo $info->id_idx."</br>";
   echo $info->name;
  } minha duvida é como selecionar a primeira linha e a segunda linha.

Comment: @EvertonFigueiredo fiz um exemplo com 2 foreachs, veja se é isto que necessita.

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu estava querendo muito obrigado e desculpa todo esse trabalho mano.

Comment: tem como eu acessar o array dentro do array tipo  echo $chars['dados']->id_idx;?

Comment: @EvertonFigueiredo não porque dentro dados tem um array do tipo index, que vai tipo 0, 1, 2, ..., pode fazer assim: `$chars['dados'][0]->id_idx` e o `$chars['dados'][1]->id_idx` pega o próximo.